# Permission denied when creating a new data set in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have to work with custom metrics and dimensions in Google Analytics. When I try to create a new data set in the admin section I see a message like permission denied. I want to upload a CSV for particular metrics, but am unable to create a dataset. Any ideas how I can grant permission for adding a new dataset?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

Short answer/solution — **in case you have multiple Google accounts, make sure you are using Google Analytics with your first (default) Google user account** (not the second, third, ...). This is because some pages are loaded with wrong user permissions (such as the data set creation page in question).

Longer answer/explanation —
Apparently this error seems to be caused by a bug in Google Analytics website (as of Nov 2020) which occurs whenever you are logged in to Google Analytics with a different Google account than the default, first account, and the default account not having access to your Google Analytics property. You can make sure you are using the default user account when you either have `?authuser=0` in the URL/address bar, or there is no such parameter present in the URL at all. This also likely explains why some users are able to create data sets in other browsers — because in other browsers, they are logging in to Google Analytics with their default user in the first place.

After I switched the default account to the one having access to the Google Analytics property, the "Permission denied" error disappeared just fine.

Comment: This worked for me! there is a lot of cases like this when having multiple logged-in users like login to Google Merchant. I'll add this to my default troubleshooting, thanks for sharing this @Martin

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate requirements to create a dataset:

1) As mentioned above, you need Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze Permissions on the property level

2) You also need to be **authenticated using a gmail.com account**. If you were given access to the property without a gmail account, you will not be able to do a data import.

Based on #2, if you go back and  [add a gmail account to the account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/72198?hl=en) that you are using to access GA, it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on the access level that you have on the **email** by which you are a**ccessing GA**.

In order for you to successfully do a data Import (new dataset) your logged in email must have

- **Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze** Permissions on the **Property level**

Once you have those permission, you can do a data Import

Comment: I can fix this issue by adding a new user, but I don't know why admin user is not able to add dataset when the secondary user has permission.

Comment: Because the admin might have the account level permission, but for this, you need to that admin again for property level permission. it is a pain from Google :).

Answer (score 0):

Safari failed for us, but Firefox worked. May have errored out coz we were logged in with multiple accounts on Safari. Started up new session in rarely used Firefox browser and worked ok.